# Finding All 3D Objects within a Certain Distance from Point

Tags: java, 3d, r-tree

I have a set of objects (let's call it `points`) that contain the x- y- and z- components of their positions within some definite space. I would like to model the interactions between the objects in `points`, however, I cannot do so unless I can quickly find the objects in the set that are less than a certain distance away from one of the objects in this set.

This undoubtedly sounds a bit unclear, so let me put it another way: if the first point in `points` has coordinates `<x, y, z>`, I would like to figure out which of the objects in `points` has a distance that is less than [some arbitrary value] from the first point.

I was considering an implementation of an R-Tree to do this in Java, yet I feel as though this is a common-enough problem that a simpler solution exists. If there is not one, I would appreciate a simple explanation of the method by which one queries an R-Tree in order to find objects that are within some distance `x` from an object in the tree, where `x` is already known.

*Edit: note that the position values of these objects will be changing*

Comment: I am missing information, if you create such "space" with some points and after that, you wont adding/removing/moving points, so pre-computing is a solution, or it will be dynamic.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question/statement. I believe that you are asking whether or not the positions will be changing: they will be<

Comment: Yea, that was what I was asking for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The R*-tree is a pretty good data structure for this, in particular when points are changing. It is designed for changes, actually.

The k-d-tree is simpler, but it doesn't support changes very well. It is designed for a one-time bulk construction.

However, as your data is only three dimensional: if your data is small enough to fit into memory, and the maximum and minimum values of x,y,z are known, an **octree** or a simple **grid** may be the tradeoff of simplicity and performance you need.

In particular if you fix your query radius beforehand, a grid-file is hard to beat. R*-trees get attractive when you need to support multiple radiuses, window queries, nearest-neighbor queries and all this.

Comment: Very interesting information - I will need to check out grid-files before I make any decisions

Comment: Gridfiles and Octrees are well suited for in-memory use. R*-trees are probably the better choice when you have to manage the data on disk; although they can work very well in memory, too.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : Square = Cube (however imagining it in 2D space would be maybe better, then you can convert it into 3D easily)

I was thinking and I think I solved it. However this is just "my" solution, I have no reference for it.

You create class "Square", which has position, width and list of points in that object.

All squares will be stored in array or hashmap based on their position, so they can be accessed quickly, if you know position you seeks.

All squares will be distributed regularly, so - from the point of view of "point instance" - you dont have to know all the existing squares to figure out in constant time in which one you belong. (example : I know there are squares with width of 40 and they are distributed by distance of 20. I am in position 10001, so I know I belong into squares in position 9980 and 10000)

Squares will be crossed by each other, therefore one point can be in more squares.

When you do something, for each point, you only check points, which are stored in squares that point belongs to. Of course - squares have to be large enough and crossed enough to achieve your goal.

When points moving, they are responsible for registering and unregistering into the squares.

---

1D EXAMPLE :

Classes : `Line segment` and `Point`

```
Attrributes:
```

`Line segment` : `int position`, `List<Points> points`

`Point` : `int position`, `List<LineSegment> lineSegments`

I want to interact only with points in distance of 20.

So I create instances of `Line segments` with width 40 and I put them one by one in distance of 20.

So they will be at positions 0, 20, 40, 60 ....

The frist one will cover area 0-40, second 20-60 etc.

I put them into the array and with known position, I can access them quickly : `arrayOfLineSegments[position/20]`

When I create point, I add him to the `line segments` it belongs to.

When I update, each point only interacts with points in lineSegments.

When I move point, it register and unregister lineSegments it belongs to.

Comment: I'll give you the upvote for thinking so critically on this, but I have to test it before I can give you the check

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop to check through the the array of object.

use the following formula: `d = sqrt[(x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 + (z1-z2)^2]`

x1,y1,z1 being the first point in `Points` and the x2,y2,z2 being the points of the object you are checking. This will check your known point vs all other points. If the distance (d) is less than your desired distance `x` then do whatever you want you program to do.

Comment: I am concerned with how long this will take. As my question states, I need to find *all* of the objects within a set distance from the object that I am considering. If my `points` set has a large number of points and I need to do this for each point, this might be very inefficient.

Comment: How can you check all of your points without checking all your points? It is a very small calculation, unless its a super massive amount of objects it should be fine

Comment: Lain - actually it is O(n^2), which is usable only for tens thousands of points.

It can be done differently to create O(n) in average case.